# Update Swipe Views fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, refresh, android-viewpager

I use code from Google example called [Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and I have one problem. I need to update view.

This init fragments:

```
private AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private void FragmentsInit()
    {
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
                {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) 
                    {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragments);
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
        {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
        }
    TabPosition=defaultPrefsGet.getInt("TabPosition",0);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(TabPosition);
    }
```

This is one of fragments, where UpdateTab1 is code, which fill view by data. Later I need update this data, which is not problem, but I don´t know how to "reload" fragment to show data.

```
public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment 
    {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list, container, false);

        UpdateTab1(rootView);

        return rootView;
        }
    }
```

I tried to find it, but I couldn´t. Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found solution, it was very simple. I juste replaced "FragmentPagerAdapter" with "FragmentStatePagerAdapter". After that I am able call "UpdateTab1" over and over and work with view as I did in activity.

Note:
I defined "*public static View viewTab1;*" to be able call UpdateTab1(viewTab1) from any part of activity.

```
public static class Fragment1 extends Fragment 
    {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list, container, false);

        viewTab1=rootView;
        UpdateTab1(viewTab1);

        return rootView;
        }
    }
```